# Função para Log

Tags: php

Pessoal peguei um codigo e ele funciona perfeitamente anota a data e o horário como eu modifiquei assim q abro a pagina! Porem na hora de colocar ele em uma função para ser disparado por um Button ele n funciona! Deve ser algo simples segue código:

```
    <?php

echo date('H:i:s');

function markLog(){
$fp = fopen('meus_links.txt', 'a');
fwrite($fp, date('H:i:s-'));
fclose($fp);
}

?>
```

```
<body>
    <button type="submit" onClick="markLog()" >Click</button>
</body>
```

Answer (score 2):

Cesar, há diferençãs aí.

Você criou uma função em PHP e a está chamando via javascript. Isto não vai funcionar. O ideal seria você trabalhar com ajax para isto. Assim você faz com que a função javascript acesse a página com o php feito.

**PHP não sabe JavaScript**
O PHP não pode chamar diretamente uma função JavaScript porque o PHP é interpretado no lado do servidor.

O PHP não vê um código ali, ele simplesmente copia o texto caractere a caractere e envia para o navegador do usuário.

**O navegador sabe JavaScript**
Quando o navegador lê os dados recebidos já em HTML, ele começa a interpretar esse HTML e montar os elementos na tela.

Ao encontrar uma tag  o nevegador pára o que está fazendo e executa o que tiver nesse script.

Note que, neste ponto, o navegador está executando o script no computador do usuário, enquanto o PHP (que possivelmente já terminou de executar) estava rodando no servidor.

Bem, vou te ajudar com ajax.

1) página php: chame-a de log.php

```
<?php

echo date('H:i:s');


$fp = fopen('meus_links.txt', 'a');
fwrite($fp, date('H:i:s-'));
fclose($fp);


?>
```

2) No seu index copie este código:

```
<form id="simples-formulario-ajax" method="post">
    <button type="submit" name="enviar" value="enviar" id="enviar">
        Clique aqui para criar um log :)
    </button> 
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$('#simples-formulario-ajax').submit(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();

    if($('#enviar').val() == 'Enviando...'){
        return(false);
    }

    $.ajax({
        url: 'log.php',
        type: 'post',
        dataType: 'html',
        data: {
            'acao': 'log'           
        }
    }).done(function(data){
        alert("Log criado com sucesso");
    });

});
</script>
```

Prontinho, funcionando que uma beleza :)